# What are some common uses of immutable data structures?

Tags: javascript, frontend, immutability, immutable.js

What motivates the increasing usage of immutable data structures such as those provided in ImmutableJS and SeamlessJS?

I know there are debugging and memory benefits.
I'm interested in uses across the JavaScript stack, but I'm also thinking of common front-end tasks that are made easier to work with or reason about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least three benefits:

- Regardless of whether it is frontend or backend work, it can [simplify your logic and work process significantly](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/). If the app has a bug, then anything you can rule out, including the inadvertent modification of some logically-immutable data structure, can help.
- It can [improve runtime performance](https://github.com/rtfeldman/seamless-immutable) when you clone objects containing them.
- I doubt these specific libraries actually use this, but immutable data structures can sometimes have better implementations. Hash tables can utilize [perfect hashing](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/perfect.html), and balanced trees can be replaced by sorted arrays.